# How to authenticate every request over a websocket in javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, websocket

Have setup a javascript server and configured the websocket to it. On the client side using react and npm. So, I want to authenticate every request to web socket using rest API. The authentication will be the first step and then all the information transfer will be happening using the same web socket after authentication is done. Is it possible to pass headers for authentication to websocket ? Can anybody please tell how to proceed ?

Below is the code for the server and client that I was experimenting with.

Server code -

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end();
});

server.listen(5005, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 5005');
});


wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
        request.reject();
          console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
    return;
    }

    console.log(" ################ Authorization ##################");   
    var auth = request.headers['authorization']; 
        if(!auth) {     
                response.statusCode = 401;
                response.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');
        console.log(" Authorization failed !!! ");
                response.end('<html><body>Need some creds son</body></html>');
        }
    else if(auth) { 
                var tmp = auth.split(' ');
                var buf = new Buffer(tmp[1], 'base64'); 
                var plain_auth = buf.toString();        

                console.log("Decoded Authorization :", plain_auth);

                var creds = plain_auth.split(':'); 
                var username = creds[0];
                var password = creds[1];

                if((username == 'hack') && (password == 'thegibson')) {   
                    console.log(" Login successful !!!");
                }
                else {
            console.log("Login failed !!");
                }
        }  


    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);

    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
       //send message 
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

Client code -

```
import React from 'react'
var client = null;
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
     return { val : [],
                  username : 'hacker',
          password : 'thegibson' };
  },

   componentWillMount: function() {
    //client = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/','echo-protocol');

    client = new WebSocket('ws://'+this.state.username+':'+this.state.password+'@localhost:5005/','echo-protocol');
        client.onerror = function() {
             console.log('Connection Error');
           };

        client.onopen = function() {
            function sendData(){        
                var details=[{"name" : "Ravi", "age" : 15, "occupation": "Student" }];              
                if (client.readyState === client.OPEN) {                
                    client.send(details.toString());
                    console.log(details);   
                    setTimeout(sendData,2000);  
                }
                }
            sendData();
             };

        client.onmessage = function(e) {
            this.setState({
                    val: e.data
            });
            }.bind(this);

    },

    componentWillUnmount: function(){
        client.close();
    },

    render: function() {
            return (React.createElement("div",null,
                    React.createElement("ul",null,
                         React.createElement("li",null,this.state.val.name," ( ", this.state.val.age,"  ) -  ","  Occupation  :", this.state.val.occupation)
                )               
            ))
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use jwt or jwe if you want to encrypt the data you send. There are many libraries you can use and full documentation here: https://jwt.io/

So you cand send via post or a header all information and check it in every HTTP or websocket call

Comment: Thanks, if you can provide any examples then it will be easy to understand.

Comment: If used it on PHP as a Client, not to communicate both server and JS client maybe [this](https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example) can help you